# Can Warhammer Fantasy vampires gain sustenance when feeding on Greenskins?

Tags: vampire, warhammer-fantasy

In Warhammer Fantasy, just like in WH40k, Greenskins (orcs, goblins, snotlings and squiggs) are, well... fungi. Sort of:

> The Runt pulled himself up out of the hole. A huge mushroom stood above his birthing-hole, wilting and black now it had served its purpose. The goblin lay on his back, panting. [...] The soil in the cavern was thin and rocky. The light was too dim. No orclings would be born there, only runty goblins and snotlings and squigs.
>
> <sub>Guy Haley, *Skarsnik*</sub>

My question is, can such creatures be used as a sustenance to the Warhammer vampires? There is a scene in *Skarsnik* where *something* tries to suck the life out of him to "use his blood to warm itself up", it never specifies this was a vampire.

<sup>Joke about "Vegetarian vampires" dropping in comment in 3, 2, 1....</sup>

Comment: This [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160532/are-orks-edible/) is kinda related, but I would think that it is possible. Vampires are mostly going for the blood for one reason or another right(?) and the greenskins do bleed as can be seen [here](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/55150/ss_9d33a17ab1d49067fceee6ee9bdee75744e0b702.1920x1080.jpg?t=1528131586).

Comment: @Odin1806: I am not sure it is related. Eating mushrooms is one thing, feeding on their "blood" is another. Is it actually blood? Maybe Orks' sap is red?

Comment: Even the color is not really cannon in 40k - in many places it has been described as black, dark green or red.

Comment: @Yasskier this question is warhammer fantasy though and not 40k

Comment: @TerranGaming I know it is about Warhammer fantasy - I've asked it! Just in the first comment Odin provided link to a picture from 40k showing bleeding Orks, hence I've replied.

Comment: In fantasy, greenskins might be hybrid animal/fungal than purely fungal: hence having "mortal blood" that can sustain vampires. https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Greenskins#Reproduction

Comment: mmm, greenskins are fantasty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**YES**

The Liber Necris (purportedly an in-universe object written by an Imperial Scholar with excerpts from one of the Von Carstein vampire counts, though I don't recall if it was Manfred or Vlad.) goes into great detail on what blood does for a vampire.  Essentially (as described in one of the Von Carstein written excerpts) the blood is merely a vector for what is actually going on.  Essentially Vampirism in Warhammer cuts off the vampire's soul from the Winds of Magic/the warp.  As a human's soul normally lives in the warp tethered to the body, this removal of the soul from the warp means the soul will slowly lose potency over time. Normally it extracts "fuel" from the warp, and vampirism stops this. To combat this vampires drink the blood of living things, which allows them to "tap" into their victim's soul-energy.  They then use that energy to "refuel" and continue existing.  This is why Abhorash was essentially able to "beat" the need to drink blood after draining a dragon.  Dragons are wildly magical, so it provided his soul "food" for hundreds or potentially thousands of years.  Meanwhile drinking the blood of a deer or other animal doesn't usually provide a lot of relief for the vampire as their souls are nowhere near what a sentient being possesses.

Orcs have souls, and thus are able to provide sustenance to vampires.  The amount of energy a vampire might get from a greenskin is probably the same as he would from a human, though there may be some sort of cost to "convert" the soul-energy of a nonhuman to something the vampire's soul can use, as they tend to dislike feeding on nonhumans.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nicely detailed answer, but you could improve it by providing a few references, like the pages in *Liber Necris* you're getting your points from, or the source for Orks having souls (that touch the Warp in the same way Human souls do).

Comment: Or non-humans just taste funny

Comment: Interesting... But I'm not 100% sure do greenskins have souls or not. For example, I've never heard about undead orcs (while there are plenty of undead humans, elves, dragons etc).

Answer (score 2):

#### Maybe not as much sustenance as from a delicious human, but they definitely get a buzz from orc blood

[W'soran](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/W%27soran) drinks the blood of an orc in one of the [Nagash](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Nagash) or [Neferata](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Neferata) novels, or maybe in [Master of Death](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19678590-master-of-death). I'll dig out the correct passage but I rememebr he drinks the blood of an orc and reacts like he has taken crystal meth.

Usually they don't, I know the [von Carsteins](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Von_Carstein) definitely avoided it, orc blood tastes pretty foul apparently.